# Remotely disable an IOS device from iPhone

Tags: ios

I would like to enable or disable my son's iPad from my iPhone so I can control the time he spends on the device. What APIs are relevant for this task. The devices are on the same home network. Or is it possible to use IOS parental control for time of day control?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This isn't the proper forum for your question

Answer (score 0):

There are quiet different apps that you can use with different features. Check out the links below:
https://itunes.apple.com/pk/app/id875252906?mt=8
https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/parental-timelock-time-limit/id689577280?mt=8
https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/timelock-time-limit-for-parents/id440218332?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4
I would recommend this link below as the best:
https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/parentkit-parental-controls/id600618138?mt=8

Comment: Thanks. The one you recommended appears to be the one closest to my requirements but has a hefty 35 dollar annual subscription. I am curious what approach and APIs would be appropriate to use if I choose to develop such an app.